# how users opt-out of c2dm message

Tags: android, android-c2dm

we are implementing c2dm to push notifications to users.  we want the user to be able to "opt-out" at the beginning.  if they opt-in, then we register the device and send the id to our server to store for later delivery and track that by some unique device id.

the problem is that there doesn't seem a reliable way in android to get a device id.  everything i've read says, "just generate a guid at first startup of the app".  well, this is fine, but if a user starts up the app, opts in, then uninstalls and re-installs the app, then opts out, i have no way of removing that old device (since the device id of the second install is new).

i've tested and an old c2dm registration id works even after an uninstall and re-install.

any suggestions?  how do others allow users to opt-out of notifications.  how do you track their devices?

Answer (score 1):

Having a Device ID is nice, but you don't need it to handle opt-outs.  When you send a C2DM message from your server, include the registration ID.  Then, when the device receives a message, it can compare the delivered registration ID with what it thinks its registration ID is.

If it matches, show the notification.  If it doesn't match, ping your server and tell it to opt-out that registration ID.

Answer (score 0):

On *first run* of your app, you could ask the user whether or not they would like to receive C2DM messages, and send that answer to your server. Then it follows that you would *only* send C2DM messages to devices that want them.

Instead of a GUID, I would look into getting their associated **Android Market** account (i.e. email address). This way, reinstalls won't change anything assuming they're using the same Android Market account.